# Android animate TextView from middle of page to the top

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, textview

I have a TextView in the middle of my page in an XML file. I'd like to move this in an animate way to the top of it's container when I click on it.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Define a translate animation in xml and put it in your res/anim folder.  Load it with AnimationUtils, then call startAnimation on your TextView passing it the loaded animation.  You can specify an animation listener to do special things if you need when the animation starts, ends, and repeats.

Comment: Any examples of this at all?

Comment: Sure.  Placed in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Define a translate animation and put it in your res/anim folder.

This one moves the view up by 175 dp, adjust android:toYDelta accordingly for your purposes.

my_anim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-175" android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Load it from code:

```
Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.my_anim);
```

Then set it on your TextView when you want it to animate:

```
myTextView.startAnimation(myAnim);
```