# How to animate a textView from the center to the top?

Tags: android, animation

I have a splash screen where I want one textview i.e the name of the app to appear in the center of the screen for 2 seconds and then animate to top of the screen and stay on top until the activity ends.

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/26807423/614807

Comment: nope i want that text to appear in the center first for 2 seconds @ChiragRaval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use post delay for it. Just get reference of the text view and pass `Runnable` with delay of `2000ms` to postDalayed of `textview`.

```
textview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myView.animate().x(center).y(top); // center is value on x and top is value of y
            }
        },2000);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate() method in View object

```
    myView.animate().x(50f).y(100f);
```